# Windows 10: ssh-ing to a Linux box and getting full xterm-color capabilities?

Tags: windows-10, ssh, powershell, conemu, windows-terminal

At the company where I work, we log in to Windows 10, and we do our development work on Linux machines where we connect via ssh login sessions. We have been able to use PuTTY for this up until recently, but now, the powers-that-be are removing access to PuTTY and forcing us to connect via other means to the Linux hosts.

Furthermore, no X-Windows capabilities are made available to us on these Linux hosts, so we just have to work with Terminal sessions. Furthermore, things are highly locked down at my company, and we cannot install our own software. We are only able to choose pre-approved software packages.

I use various linux programs such as vim and emacs which have color capabilties and which make use of syntax highlighting. However, I have not found any way to ssh in to linux via any Windows terminal programs where I can get this syntax highlighting to work properly with these linux programs.

I have tried PowerShell, WindowsTerminal, and ConEMU, and none of them give me full control over colors during the ssh sessions to the Linux box. I'm talking about full TERM=xterm-color capabilities.

Can anyone suggest any ways to configure PowerShell, WindowsTerminal, or ConEMU to give me the same control over colors in ssh shells to linux that I have been able to take advantage of via TERM=xterm-color when using PuTTY?

Comment: Are the PTB allowing the creation of a virtual machine that you control fully?

Comment: Colors in Linux apps work OK for me using Windows 10 ssh. I think the ssh I use  is the optional one provided with Windows. ssh -V reports OpenSSH_for_Windows_8.1p1, LibreSSL 3.0.2. Linux sees TERM as xterm-256color. this ssh seems to be the one in Control-Panel, "Apps", "Apps & features", "Optional Features", "OpenSSH Client"

Comment: @RedGrittyBrick What Linux flavor do you use? This might help. I think the same worked for me in the past with Ubuntu.

Comment: @HippoMan same for you 

Comment: I tested just now with an old Raspbian system, but I have the same experience at work with RHEL 8.7. Two different Windows 10 PCs, both using the ssh that came with Windows as far as I know.

Comment: I just tried it after setting up sshd under Ubuntu 20 under WSL. I can ssh to Ubuntu and see colorised output from `ls`.

Comment: Thank you to all! To @RedGrittyBrick, which Windows terminal program are you using? Have you tried using the console version of emacs (i.e., "emacs -nw filename") under linux? Does the text get colorized? I can't make that colorization happen when connecting via any of the Windows terminal programs via ssh to an RHEL host.

Comment: PS: The PTB don't allow us much of any control over our VPS's. They are really big on locking things down where I work.

Comment: @HippoMan, I get syntax highlighting in Vim - so it baffles me why you aren't getting syntax highlighting in Emacs and other programs. If I knew why I would certainly write an answer. My comments mainly serve to suggest that a solution probably exists. What do you get from `echo $TERM`? I get `xterm-256color`. I am running ssh from a normal Windows command prompt (cmd.exe).

Comment: Thank you again! And yes, my situation is the same as yours. I tried from the normal cmd.exe this time, and after connecting to linux, $TERM == xterm-256color. And under Windows, ssh -V reports OpenSSH_for_Windows_8.1p1, LibreSSL 3.0.2.  So, my issue is something beyond this, most likely something with my own, personal linix shell setup. I'll keep investigating, and I'll report back here with whatever I figure out.

Comment: I figured it out!!! I'm writing my Answer now. Thank you again for everything!

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that my problem wasn't due to color-setting sequences being unrecognized on the linux machine that I connected to via ssh. The colors work fine when I connect via standard Windows ssh (OpenSSH_for_Windows_8.1p1, LibreSSL 3.0.2).

My problem actually had to do with keystroke recognition. In emacs (which I normally use), I have sequences such as Ctrl-Spacebar mapped to certain commands, and by coincidence, one of those commands toggles syntax highlighting. Because Ctrl-Spacebar was not honored, then my syntax highlighting never took place, and I mistakenly thought that the color settings were not being recognized.

When I reconfigured emacs to also accept an alternate sequence for what I had mapped Ctrl-Spacebar to, then my syntax highlighting worked perfectly.

Apparently, Ctrl-Spacebar and some of my other keyboard mappings are not recognized keyboard sequences in cmd.exe, in PowerShell, in WindowsTerminal, and in ConEmu.

I just discovered that this Ctrl-Spacebar thing is a known bug.

https://github.com/microsoft/terminal/issues/2865